# SOLR search field type of "textCollection" and "Coordinates" are not generated in schema.xml when using SXA

Tags: solr, content-search, sxa

- Sitecore 8.2.4
- SXA 1.4

I have configured solr with all required installation and configuration outlined by the Sitecore Documentation site. I have enabled the following sxa solr config for SXA search components.

**Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Solr.config**

I noticed below two new return types in this config file.

```
<typeMatch typeName="textCollection" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_tm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
<typeMatch typeName="coordinates" type="System.String" fieldNameFormat="{0}_rpt" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
```

When I generated the solr schema file using below Sitecore solr schema file generator, it does not generate dynamic field extentions for **"_tm"** and **"_rpt"**.

- How do get these fields extentions created in solr schema.xml using sitecore solr schema file generator?
- Do I have to manually to add these two extention?

[image]

Comment: The Schema.xml generator is pretty basic, and depending on your version of both Sitecore and SOLR probably needs to be manually adjusted anyways. I would suggest manually adding the new extensions and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

We found that adding the following to the `schema.xml` in your Solr cores for **master** and **web** helped get the search working for content and geospatial searches.

```
<dynamicField name="*_tm" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="geolocation_rpt" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true" />
```